# Is it okay to have a hashcode as a simple increment?

Tags: java, hash

Is this code below okay for a hashCodeto be a simple increment starting with a negative number?

```
private volatile static AtomicInteger creations = new AtomicInteger(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
private final int creation;

{
    creation = creations.getAndIncrement();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return creation;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    if (creation == ((Stuff) obj).creation)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

How come hashCodes are usually made with prime numbers instead of using just a simple increment? (The reason why I want it to be this way is because each object I create with this class will be unique and I want to be able to remove it from a HashMap later even though the state of the object will change, because it is my understanding if a Hash changes then you cannot remove it from a HashMap after it was added) To prevent this from being a simple yes or no answer, maybe explain to me the pros and cons of implementing a Hash this way.

Comment: "How come hashCodes are usually made with prime numbers instead of using just a simple increment?"  First, I don't think hash codes are usually prime numbers; hash **tables** often have prime numbers as sizes, but that's a totally different thing.  Second, using a simple increment works in your case because you only have the one field and that field happens to be the increment.  But that's an extremely unusual case.  In most real-life cases, using an incremented value as a hash code is a big fail, unless there are never two different objects that are equal, and then the increment is pointless.

Comment: @ajb the reason why I never want two objects to have the same hash and the reason why I want the hash calculated this way is because in a HashMap I can't remove an element if it's Hash changed. So basically that disqualifies me from being able to have a Hash based on state for my objects which are constantly changing states.

Comment: OK, that's _your_ use case.  But if you're asking why hash codes aren't usually computed using just a simple increment, it's because your use case is not typical.  And this method will not work in the typical case where elements are put in a hash table.

Comment: @ajb why would it not work when elements are put in a hash table? Will it render the performance boost of a hash table useless? the reason why I want to do this is because I specifically can't remove things from a hash table when the hash changes.

Comment: If you could have two different objects that are "equal", such as two `Strings` that do not compare equal with `==` but compare equal with `.equals`, then your hash code approach will not work at all.  Two objects that return true for `.equals` _must_ have the same hash code, or else hash maps will fail.  And that is a much more common use case.  Objects that change state aren't typically used as hash map keys.

Comment: @ajb what performance difference would I see for a HashMap? Maybe you are right about this and I do not really need or want to use a HashMap at all. I just want to add lots of elements to an array but also remove them quickly and add more every second. I figured a HashMap would allow me to add and remove quicker than a regular ArrayList, I guess I will find out doing some benchmarks but perhaps you already know that answer.

Comment: It's occurred to me that you haven't told us what you're using a HashMap for.  (And I don't mean "for better performance".  I mean, what are you actually doing with it?  And why do you want to use these objects as HashMap keys?)

Comment: @ajb to basically simplify the situation, I want to add thousands of objects to an array, but then I want to remove many of those objects from the array based on certain criteria and also add to the array and iterate through it quickly also like every second. I want to do this very quickly like thousands of objects a second. Right now my current implementation works pretty good for up to 10,000 objects before it starts to lag. I guess I am still trying to figure out how HashMap keys will help me or if they even can. I was just thinking the HashMap was more optimized to add and remove things.

Comment: No, HashMaps are optimized for looking things up, not for adding and removing things.  Maybe you're thinking of a HashSet, which is a HashMap without values.  Even then, it's optimized for testing whether an object is in the set, not for adding or removing.  If your main operations are adding, removing, and iterating through all elements, you probably want a doubly linked list, not a HashMap or HashSet.

Comment: @ajb that is what I am thinking, the only reason I was thinking HashSet would be good was because of this `This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size)` I'm definitely going to run a benchmark to see the actual performance differences of using a linkedlist vs hashset for my particular application.

Comment: Doubly linked lists also offer constant time performance for add and remove (assuming you don't care about the order); and they can offer constant time performance for "size" if the size is kept and maintained for the list.  The constant time used by a doubly linked list should be slightly smaller than for a HashSet.  "Contains" is the one area where a HashSet beats a list.

Answer (score 2):

In general it's not okay. Two objects for which `object1.equals(object2)` returns true must have the same `hashCode`.

However, in your specific case, where the only criteria for object equality is the creation property, which is the same property used in the `hashCode`, your `hashCode` is fine.

However, your `hashCode` and `equals` don't offer much benefit over the default implementations of `Object`, since `a.equals(b)` will be true if and only if `a==b`.

Comment: @assylias I only read the OP's equals method after posting my answer. Edited the answer now.

Comment: I think the title is confusing.  If you read just the title, the answer is generally "no".

Comment: The reason why I want this sort of hashCode is because I want to have the performance benefits of a HashMap but you can't remove elements if the Hash has changed so I guess that is the tradeoff of having equality based on the state of an object.

Comment: @CodeCamper Then why bother overriding hashCode and equals at all? Just use the default implementation of the Object class.

Comment: @ajb [this is what I am talking about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266476/hashset-remove-element-upon-condition) , basically I discovered that if you add an element to a HashSet or HashMap and the Hash changes because you have equality based on some sort of state, it makes it so you can't remove that element. Maybe I am mistaken or grossly confused but if you click that link you will see what I mean.

Comment: @Eran the reason why I was overriding is because I was creating a subclass from a class I didn't create which already had a hashCode and equal in place which was based on the objects state. And it just hit me that I am trying to implement the default implementation but now it makes me wonder, will my hashCode actually result in less collisions since I am utilizing every integer value possible incrementally?

Comment: @CodeCamper Your design may be a problem.  I don't know what class you're extending.  But if it's a class that's immutable, i.e. it never changes state once it's been initialized, and you're creating a subclass that does change state and in which two distinct objects are never equal, then you appear to be violating the Liskov Substitution Principle and shouldn't be using inheritance.  I can't say for sure because I don't know the details.  It could be that the class you didn't create is the poorly designed one.

Comment: @CodeCamper I doubt if your hashCode would have any noticeable performance difference compared to the default implementation.

Comment: @Eran the real question is will I see a performance difference of HashMap vs ArrayList because at the moment I switched from HashMap to ArrayList because my Hash was changing because the objects state constantly changed so it wouldn't remove the element because it looks for the old hash or something like that. But now that I am putting the HashCode back to the default I can use a HashMap. I guess I will run some benchmarks and find out. What I am doing is constantly adding and removing hundreds of objects from arrays every second and also looping through them all.

Comment: @CodeCamper It's just occurred to me: what are you using a HashMap for at all?  HashMaps are there so that you can give it a "key" and get a "value" out.  But if you want each distinct object to be a unique key, rather than having two objects that are equal in some way (such as equal Strings) be the same key, then why do you need a HashMap to retrieve a value for each unique object?  Why not just stick the values in the objects themselves?

Comment: @ajb Exactly, right now I am using an ArrayList, I guess there is no reason for me to use a HashMap? For some reason I thought the add and remove functions were optimized somehow but I guess they are meaningless if I don't really have any buckets... well anyway I am more familiarized with all these concepts now, thanks for your help and everyone else too!

Comment: @CodeCamper Part of the problem is that your description of what you're doing is very vague.  You're adding and removing things.  That's about all we know.  On the face of it, that doesn't sound like a problem for which a HashMap is the right tool.  Maybe if you post some code that shows how you intend to use a HashMap, it would help us help you solve your problem.

Comment: @ajb I'll have to make it as another question, but for now I will do some testing myself then maybe post some benchmarks of two ways of doing it that I can think of and then ask for a faster solution. Because I'm surprised how some of these things are so micro-optimizing they don't even make a difference for thousands of iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's ok (if two instances are equals, they have the same hashcode) although your equals/hashcode implementation is not doing much vs. the default implementation of Object so there is no point doing that - unless you want objects to be equal every 2^32 instance creation.

Based on your additions, I would agree with Patricia Shanahan's suggestion to use `identityHashCode`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return System.identityHashCode(this);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
 return this == obj;
}
```

That is essentially what Object does by default. In terms of collisions, I doubt that you will have more collision with this implementation than yours.

Comment: for some reason I did not think of this... so it really would yield the same result as the default implementation? I am overriding class at the moment with my class. Is there a way I can restore the default implementation or is the way I implemented it pretty much the best way to do that?

Comment: @CodeCamper Just remove the two methods and you will inherit the default implementation from Object.

Comment: For this particular example I am extending a class that is not my code. Should I just copy and paste the source code into my own class and remove those two methods because right now extending the class keeps things nice and clean for me and I guess there is no way to remove the methods from the subclass in that manner. Also how do I avoid objects being equal every 2^32 instance creation because isn't HashCode limited to Integer anyway? At first I wanted the HashCode to be long until I realized it was int by design.

Comment: Write an equals that just does what Object's equals does. Write a hashCode method that uses [System.identityHashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan thanks! one question though. Will my hashCode implementation above actually result in less collisions since I am making use of every available integer value? Or does the identityHashCode do the same thing?

Comment: Please note the default implementation is not *guaranteed* to be distinct for distinct objects. It is (theoretically) possible to find objects a and b such that (a.hashCode()==b.hashCode()&&a!=b) is true. In most implementations it is wildly unlikely - but possible.

Comment: @DanAllen I am creating tens of thousands of objects so I guess my implementation would actually be better since I am guaranteed no collision until 2^32. ` (a.hashCode()==b.hashCode()&&a!=b)` this code is awfully confusing but it makes sense, when you do a==b and a!=b what is it really comparing the internal pointers?

Comment: @CodeCamper It might be better if, and only if, you can be sure your objects will only ever be stored in a one class data structure. However, you can sure both that the default has been measured with the common data structures, and that any hashCode using data structure is likely to have been tested and measured with the default.

Comment: @CodeCamper You can imagine so. It's not defined how it's achieved and you could build a JVM where threads cache objects and use synchronization to maintain coherence. What is clear is that there's a gap between the two specifications. Compare the description of the default implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: @CodeCamper Here's a JVM where using the internal object pointer won't work: https://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/projects/systems/cjvm/index.html